# How to download maven dependencies from Jenkins without a binary repository

Tags: maven, jenkins

Are there any plugins or ways to download the dependencies for a maven project from Jenkins? I am using Jenkins for a multi-module desktop application. Although I know I could just archive all dependencies, I don't see why there isn't the ability to download dependencies using maven which installed on the same machine as Jenkins. Preferably one would specify the location of a pom and then have the ability with one click to download all the dependencies for that pom. Can you do this? I do not need or want an entire binary repository for this feature.

**Edit:** I will try and rephrase this as I don't think people are understanding.

In Jenkins one has the ability to archive artifacts at the end of a build. Also in jenkins you have integration with maven. When building a jar in maven you have arguablly 2 options:

1. You can either use the assembly plugin which zips all .class files
   together with those produced from your source code resulting in 1 jar
2. You can create a jar just source code which references all
   dependency jars which are located in a separate folder.

In Jenkins one also has the ability to download the latest artifact. Now if I am using **Option 2**, I can either archieve just the jar which my sources produced, which I would say is more desirable for space and is the whole purpose of the archive functionality, or you can also archive the libraries too.

Here is the **PROBLEM!**! If I don't archive the libraries then I cannot easily run this jar, as it is a desktop application and its dependencies cannot be obtained in the same mannor as clicking on a link from jenkins. So lets say my question is what is the easiest way to obtain them? Extra info: assume jenkins is running as a server and you can't use artifactory or another server application, that seems to me to be massive over kill.

Comment: You can use a plugin in Jenkins which can provide a repository for Maven.

Comment: you want to download dependencies from mirror?

Comment: I don't care where they come from, I just want the interface in jenkins to be able to download them to my pc, otherwise I can only download the jar which my sources produce via archive artifact, yet I can't run it without its dependencies. (At the moment I am using the mvn asembly:single and archiving a fat jar which I'm not happy about)

Comment: Ok let me rephrase your question: You do not want to pack your dependencies into your projects jar. And because of that, you are looking for a way that jenkins provides links to all dependencies of your project. And then you want to download them to the machine your jar will run on? For this you could use mvn dependency:copy-dependencies. You can either run this locally or jenkins as job - putting the files into a directory you can download them from.

Comment: I think that is the way to go, thankyou mithrandir. When I have tried this method I will post all the steps. (gave upvote too)

Answer (score 1):

Use the maven plugin and create a maven job for your project. Jenkins will then use the maven command you provide in the job configuration to build the project. This means maven will download the projects dependencies and store them on the machine jenkins is running. Normally this would be `<JENKINS_HOME>/.m2/repository`. This way you get a local repository that only contains the dependencies of the projects you created maven jobs for.

Comment: I think usually it would be M2_HOME/.m2/respository if you configure maven to use the maven you have installed. But anyway please read the question again I have edited it.